# Invert a mask IP Address (Wildcard mask)

Tags: c#, .net, wildcard, mask

I try to convert the format of a Mask IP Address (called wildcard mask).
I want, for example,

1. SubnetMask 0.0.0.3 should return 255.255.255.252.
2. SubnetMask 0.0.1.255 should return 255.255.254.0

Somebody have any clue how I can do this?
In theory, it should be simple as i only need to invert all the bits in the bytes.
I think my function to Invert bits is not working? How could i perform that?
Thankk you !! :)

---

```
//Retreive IP Subnet Mask (ex: Format 0.0.0.255)
IPAddress SubnetMask = IPAddress.Parse(template_script[line_delimiter].Split(' ')[2]);

//Retreive bytes array of Mask
byte[] bytes = SubnetMask.GetAddressBytes();

//Reverse all bit in bytes
byte[] reversed = Function.InvertBits(bytes);

//Retreive IP Address of inverted byte array
IPAddress SubnetMask_inverted = new IPAddress(reversed);

MessageBox.Show("Subnet original: " + SubnetMask.ToString() + "\nSubnet inverted : " + SubnetMask_inverted.ToString());
```

Comment: Do you just want `255-x` for each byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the math you do in `ReverseBits` is a little wrong, also the proper term for what you are trying to is `Invert`, here is how I would have done it.

```
public static void InvertArray(byte[] array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (byte)(255 - array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what i needed! as simple as that. it is working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Another, slightly more efficant way, is to directly invert the bits using the [bitwise NOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d2bd4x66(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public static void InvertArray(byte[] array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (byte)~array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, still need the cast, unfortunatly